# How can I get just 1 row from multi rows have same value in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

For example, I have a table "person" with column "name" and have rows like this:

1.John

2.Jerry

3.Jessy

4.John

5.Jessy

....

What I want is to get all records but for rows have same value, I just take 1 row.Please tell me how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can just use GROUP BY on the column(s) that should be unique, and MAX() on any other column:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(x) AS x, y, z...
FROM person
GROUP BY Name;
```

(In earlier SQLite versions, the other column values are not guaranteed to come from the same row.)

Answer (score 0):

How about use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, SOME_COL1, SOME_COL2 FROM PERSON;
```

Comment: I want to take all comlumns,not specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for, is the keyword DISTINCT.

SELECT DISTINCT name FROM person

The rest of the records can't be selected, because you have e.g. different records for the same name 'John'. You can only use aggregate functions for the rest of the field combined with the keyword GROUP BY.

SELECT name, MAX(age), SUM(income) FROM person GROUP BY name

Comment: The "name" column is just to compare, what I want is to get other columns as well, so SELECT DISTINCT is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thank to everybody's help, it is very easy.Just use this query statement:

```
"Select * from person group by name"
```